# Perl, how to read argv as hash?

Tags: perl, argv

So, I've read some guides about how to use `Getopt::Long` and similar libs to work with `argv` options, and still has no clue how to use it properly because of totally unclear (as for me) documentation and guides.

I have a script. It has next arguments:
`-qp`,
`-pr`,
`-rp`,
`-vr`, and most of them are for filenames.

Currently I have this use of `Getopt::Long`, which I find unsuitable because I need to check what is after option every time:

```
for(my $i = 0; $i < @ARGV; $i+=2){
    if ($ARGV[$i] eq "-qp"){
        unless ($ARGV[$i+1] eq "-vr" or $ARGV[$i+1] eq "-pr" or $ARGV[$i+1] eq "-rp"){
            $query_params = $ARGV[$i+1];
        }
    }
    elsif ($ARGV[$i] eq "-pr"){
        unless ($ARGV[$i+1] eq "-qp" or $ARGV[$i+1] eq "-pr" or $ARGV[$i+1] eq "-rp"){
            $params = $ARGV[$i+1];
        }
    }
    elsif ($ARGV[$i] eq "-vr"){
        unless ($ARGV[$i+1] eq "-vr" or $ARGV[$i+1] eq "-qp" or $ARGV[$i+1] eq "-rp"){
            $variables = $ARGV[$i+1];
        }
    }
    elsif ($ARGV[$i] eq "-rp"){
        unless ($ARGV[$i+1] eq "-qp" or $ARGV[$i+1] eq "-pr" or $ARGV[$i+1] eq "-vr"){
            $replace = $ARGV[$i+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I don't need to use exact `Getopt` libs for `Unix`, I need just to pass some `args` to script. Is there any way to make it more simple and correct?

Comment: What do you mean, "*this use of Getopt::Long*"? That code doesn't use any module.

Comment: By convention, most commands use single-letter options with a hyphen (`-a -b -c`) and long options with a double hyphen (`--foo --bar`). Your syntax is a bit weird.

Comment: @melpomene It's actually in `use`, i just brought a piece of code.

Comment: Your code may load `Getopt::Long`, but it still doesn't make use of it. Why bother writing `use Getopt::Long` when you're going to parse `@ARGV` by hand?

Comment: @melpomene the question is how to grab argv as hash, and not alowing the situation like `perl script.pl -qp -pr` where `-qp` gets `-pr` and not `undef`.

Comment: ... why? That's completely unlike how any other command-line program works. It looks like the reason you're having trouble getting this to work "properly" is that your definition of "proper" would be considered broken by getopt standards.

Comment: I agree with @melpomene. If you want that behaviour, you need to build it yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to your claims, you aren't using Getopt::Long. But you should!

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

use File::Basename qw( basename );
use Getopt::Long   qw( );

my %opts; 

sub parse_args {
   %opts = ();
   Getopt::Long::Configure(qw( posix_default ));
   GetOptions(
      'help|h|?' => \&help,
      'qp:s' => \$opts{qp},
      'pr:s' => \$opts{pr},
      'rp:s' => \$opts{rp},
      'vr:s' => \$opts{vr},
   )
      or usage();
}

parse_args();
```

Using `:s` instead of `=s` makes the option's argument optional as requested in the comments.

Sample helper subs to complete the above:

```
sub help {
   my $prog = basename($0);
   say "usage: $prog [options]";
   say "       $prog --help";
   say "";
   say "Options:";
   say "   --qp path   ...explanation...";
   say "   --qp        ...explanation...";
   say "   --pr path   ...explanation...";
   say "   --pr        ...explanation...";
   say "   --rp path   ...explanation...";
   say "   --rp        ...explanation...";
   say "   --vr path   ...explanation...";
   say "   --vr        ...explanation...";
   exit(0);
}

sub usage {
   my $prog = basename($0);
   warn(@_) if @_;
   warn("Try `$prog --help' for more information\n");
   exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A quick example from the docs of `Getopt::Long`.

You could now call this script with `script --qp=file1 --pr=file2 --rp=file2`

What `Getopt:Long` does for you is sort out the values given on command line to where you tell it to put them, as well as some basic validation (the `=s` here means you're expecting a string).

If you want to check, for example, that the given files exist, you need to do that by hand.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

my ($qp,$pr,$rp);
my $verbose;

GetOptions (
    "qp=s" => \$qp,
    "pr=s" => \$pr,
    "rp=s" => \$rp,
    "verbose" => \$verbose,
) or die "Error in command line arguments";

print "Being verbose.\n" if $verbose;

# Quick check all are there if they're all required (?)
die "qp,pr and rp are required!" if grep{ !$_ }($qp,$pr,$rp);

for my $fn ( $qp,$pr,$rp ){
    die "Cannot find file '$fn'" unless -f $fn;
}

print "you've given: qp $qp, pr $pr, rp $rp.\n";
```